# Como obter os valores de um objeto de uma array retornada do Laravel?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

Preciso pegar os valores um array que está sendo retornado do laravel, mas não estou conseguindo entender como fazer isso.

Laravel:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response()->json([
                    $prod->unique()
                ]);
            }
```

Array:

```
[
   [
      {
         "id":3,
         "nome":"Cerveja HEINEKEN Garrafa 330ml",
         "preco":"4,80",
         "tamanho":"330ml",
         "desc":null,
         "imagem":"0310412021060360b848319b870.jpg",
         "qunt":"37",
         "categoria":"1",
         "created_at":"2021-06-03 03:10:41",
         "updated_at":"2021-06-17 02:33:05"
      }
   ]
]
```

Quero ter acesso a cada um dos valores através de JavaScript.

Ex:

```
<script>

   ....

    success: function(data) {

      alert(***Queria o preco aqui***);

    },

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce tera que correr cada array do json retornado. Vc pode usar a funcao `$.each` do jQuery para interagir com o seu array/objeto:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data[0], function(i, produto){
        alert(produto['preco']);
    });
},
```

Ou, caso vc retorne mais dados nesse array no futuro, voce pode tambem organizar melhor os dados retornados pelo Laravel:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response()->json([
        'produtos' => $prod->unique()
    ]);
}
```

JS

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.produtos, function(i, produto){
        alert(produto.preco);
    });
},
```

Comment: Nossa cara! obrigado nunca pensei que seria tão simples assim. Muito obrigado msm.